# What is ruby-build-github?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rbenv, github-pages

What exactly is [ruby-build-github](https://github.com/parkr/ruby-build-github), and why should I use it instead of the normal ruby builds?

*I came across it while looking into installing Jekyll and using Github Pages.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes it easy to install github's fork of ruby (either with rbenv or on its own).

Github's ruby doesn't vary dramatically from "normal" MRI - it's largely backports of things that will be released as part of normal ruby later on.

Github seem to roll out new versions of ruby quite aggressively (according to this [gist]https://gist.github.com/tmm1/8393897) they were running 2.1.0 in production only a fortnight or so after it was released and had run into some of the sharp edges you might expect to encounter.

In general you would have to take a view as to whether you were interested in any of the patches they had applied to mainline ruby, which will of course vary over time